# Слово человецех

Tags: слова

> Надобны для этого любовь и в человецех благоволение.

Я выяснил, что это фрагмент из Евангелия. Но русское ли вообще слово *человецех*, или, может, это слово из церковнославянского?

Comment: Вы выбрали довольно трудную книгу для перевода, в ней много аллюзий и разговорного языка: Куда мы денемся с этой подводной, вернее, подземной лодки...
 Есть ли жизнь за МКАДом.
 Правда, теперь не поймешь, кто из нас кто? То есть одна сатана, а? – спросила она.
– Но только высоко-высоко у Царских врат, – прошептала Катя, – причастный к тайнам, плакал ребёнок, о том, что никто не придёт назад.
Поговаривают, что живёт где-то Чёрный Пёс Петербург.
...разница между богатством и нищетой заключается в обладании куском конины...

Comment: Да, но выбирая, я не знал, что она трудна. куда мы денемся - куда уйдём (пол. gdzie się podziejemy), подземная лодка - это метро, но не знаю почему это точно лодка.  МКАД - это легко проверить - это кольцевая дорога в Москве. Царские врата - это главные врата в православной церкви, которыми проходить может только батюшка. Остальных я не заметил особенно, можете ли их объяснить?

Comment: вы умеете открывать чат?

Comment: 1. Куда ты денешься с подводной лодки — это из анекдота: "Вечерняя поверка на подводной лодке:
- Иванов?
- Я!
- Петров?
- Я!
- Сидоров?
- ...
- Сидоров!
- ...
- Сидоров!!!
- Ну я.
- Уф! (облегченно) А куда ты денешься..."

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, в чате, если это лучше.

Comment: 2. Первоисточник этой фразы — «Есть ли жизнь на Марсе?». Это была тема лекции в классическом советском фильме «Карнавальная ночь». Посмотрите обязательно! А в наше время, для москвичей жизнь за МКАДом — как жизнь на Марсе, непонятно, есть ли она.

Comment: Так я не умею его открывать. А может, у меня на чат репутации не хватает

Comment: продолжаю 3. Намек на пословицу «муж и жена — одна сатана». 4. Катя цитирует [стихотворение Блока](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5_%28%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%29). Тут становится понятно, что никто в этой истории не придёт назад.

Comment: 5. [Чёрный Пёс Петербург](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%91%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)

Comment: 6. « ...разница между богатством и нищетой заключается в обладании куском конины... »— там длинная цитата из «1984», гуглите!

Comment: Все, мне пора уходить. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! 1984 я читал, долго назад, но этой цитаты я не помнил :) А остальных аллюзий я не открыл бы без вас!

Comment: Я начала читать эту книгу, но бросила, когда начались кровавые разборки. Фантастику я люблю, но без крови. А в этой книге наверняка есть еще цитаты. Все странные фразы надо гуглить. Когда закончите перевод, можно еще попробовать задать здесь вопрос, — какие еще произведения здесь цитируются, со списком уже найденных. Я думаю, найдутся желающие прочитать книгу и накидать ответов за прибавку к репутации. Я только не уверена, что это по теме форума.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a Church Slavonic word.

Modern Russian does not use plural of *человек* at all (it would be *в людях*), and even if it would do, it would revert the second palatalization on the morpheme boundary (that is, it would be **в человеках*)

Comment: _Человеки_ / _человеках_ всё еще допустимо как архаизм.